# Subscribing to Firebase topic is not filtering messages

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending messages to my android client app using a node.js server. The client subscribe to a topic in `OnCreate()`, and the server sends messages to that topic. However, my client is also receiving messages from other topics as well. I'd like the client to only receive firebase messages to which it is subscribe to.

Here's my topic subscription code in `OnCreate()`:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("7071")
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            String msg = "Subscribed to firebase topic " + "7071";
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                msg = "Firebase topic subscribing failed";
            }
            Log.d(TAG, msg);
        }
    });
```

Here's how I am receiving messages in my Firebase messaging service class:

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
}
```

And here's how I am sending from my node.js server

```
var message = {
    data: { alpha: 'A' }
};

var options = {
  "priority": "high",  
  "timeToLive": 0
}

admin.messaging().sendToTopic("9090", message, options); //This message shouldn't be received as it is on a different topic
```

Here's my log:

```
D/HomeSoundDebug: Subscribed to firebase topic 7071
D/HomeSoundDebug: From: /topics/9090
```

The second line (from `remoteMessage.getFrom()` above) shouldn't come.

Any help?

Comment: Hi, did you find why the filter is not applyied ? I'm facing the same issue on nestjs